# SQLIOSIM fails to run when using UNC path

Tags: sql-server, storage, performance, performance-testing

I'm trying to run SQLIOSIM on NAS cluster's NTFS shared folder.
Here's the command line:

> sqliosim.com -dir \\c16\vol1cifs -size 512 -d 600

But it repeatedly fails to create files during the setup due to following error:

> Error: 0x80070057  Error Text:   Description: Unable to get volume
>   name for mount point \\c16\vol1cifs\

vol1cifs - NTFS shared folder, that can be opened and edited on the same client where
SQLIOSIM is installed, without any problem.
According to SQLIOSIM description it does supports UNC path.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for help.
Sam

Comment: Does the account have access to the mount point or shared location ?

Comment: I can open shared folder from the same client (\\c16\vol1cifs) and able to create and edit files as well

Comment: Try adding a folder inside the share, like \\c16\vol1cifs\sqliosimtests, and grant full read/write access on that share to the public. (Just making sure it's not a permissions problem.)

Comment: Thanks Brent, did that, but still the same result. It is writable by any other command from the same command line but SQLIOSIM fails. I even tried to run SQLIOSIM on shared folder of other windows client (in case there are server problems) but it fails to write via UNC path to windows client as well. I suspect there maybe some issue with SQLIOSIM and UNC path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, technically I'd solved the problem, although there's still question about weird sqliosim behavior.

It appears that sqliosim do creates it's files in shared NAS folder (sqliosim.mdx, sqliosim.mdx) but for some reason I can't explain, it fails to resize files and aborts.

Workaround:
Create files before sqliosim run, with exactly the same size it expects, 
I.e:
fstool file createnew \\SERVER\shared FOLDER\sqliosim.ldx [size in BYTES]

Repeat the same action for sqliosom.mdx
Now run sqliosim and make yousrlf a coffee. :)

Thank you.
Sam